# Does the number of parameters of a CNN have an impact on the speed and time to train it?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, optimization

I would like to know if the Number of parameters has a role to play when it come to time to train or speed of calculation in a CNN.
I know that increasing the num of params we can increasing the modeling capacity of the network but which also increases the possibility that the network could over fit. But I would guess that lower no of params means that the total num of mathamatical calculations at test time would be less hence faster. And training with lower params should be faster as there are fewer params.

I would like to know if what I have inferred is true.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is true. Convolution with bigger filters requires more calculations, so does doing more convolutions. An exception might be for example this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5851.
Here they use Fourier-transform to turn convolution in the multiplication of the Fourier coefficients. However they pad their filter to the size of the image before transforming it.